# Spring Boot - Disable embedded ElasticSearch without removing code or changing POM

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to prevent ElasticSearch for starting (embedded or separate server) in a Spring Boot project. ES is currently not in use, but will be at a later stage in the project.

If I remove the lines from the POM, my code needs major updates, because all annotations to ES cannot be found anymore.

Is there a way I can keep my project intact, but prevent ES from launching (embedded)?

My goal is to speed up restarts for the time being, when ES is not in use.

Or course, I could also run ES as a separate server, but I don't want to spend the time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to create an ES client to your yet non-existent remote ES server so that you don't see connection issues in the logs? You're not embedding an ES server inside your spring-boot app, are you?

Comment: Yes, by default Spring Boot starts an embedded server, but I don't want it :)

Answer (score 7):

Add the following `exclude` to your `@SpringBootApplication`

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: I have added this, but I can still see ES being run. The console reports things like: 2016-12-19 13:22:13.110  WARN 56711 --- [anagement][T#1]] o.e.cluster.routing.allocation.decider   : [Adaptoid] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [zc2jESkCR1OXqOoA6eri5g][Adaptoid][/.../data/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 46.1gb[9.9%], shards will be relocated away from this node

Comment: Try `exclude = {ElasticsearchConfiguration.class}`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. An embedded ES is still started.

Answer (score 3):

In your local `application.properties`

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration
```

In production override to force the connection

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes = someip:9300
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = none
```

Probability you will need to make ElasticsearchTemplate `@Lazy` or put it under a `@Profile("production")` class

Answer (score 3):

In case your are using Java High Level REST Client, then the solution is as the following:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RestClientAutoConfiguration.class`)

Answer (score 1):

I found this way to disable/enable Elasticsearch in Spring Boot

> in application.properties:

```
elastic_enable=false
```

> in elastic config file:

```
@Value("${elastic_enable}") boolean elastic_enable;

@Bean public Client a() throws UnknownHostException {
    if (elastic_enable) 
        return TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elastic_host), 9300));
    else 
        return TransportClient.builder().build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude this two Spring Boot Auto Configurations:

```
ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class
```

Also if you have `@Configuration` class for your Elastic or `@Bean` for the `ElasticsearchTemplate` be sure to comment them out.

Answer (score 1):

I have just disabled embedded elasticsearch in spring boot 1.5.8 by adding the following exclude to my @SpringBootApplication.

Hope this can help.

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class,ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
```