# Spring Boot Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a spring boot project with spring data elasticsearch integrated into it. Is it possible to run spring boot without running elasticsearch locally? At the moment, if I do not run elasticsearch locally, my spring boot application does not start due to a connect exception.

Exceptions:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService'`

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not quite the answer to your question, but maybe an alternative: You could run Elasticsearch locally in a docker container: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of autoconfiguration kicks in at the start up. You can try disabling the auto configuation using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221927/spring-boot-disable-embedded-elasticsearch-without-removing-code-or-changing-p)